# LED that emits light in different direction

Tags: led, pcb

Is there such a thing as an LED that emits its light horizontally ("to the side") when mounted on a PCB instead of the ususal "up" direction? If so, what are these called, and do they use the same standardized footprints as normal LEDs (1206, 0805, etc.)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, many, many of them (I see 900 or so individual types in stock at Digikey).

The naming is not standardized. It could be "right angle" (RA) or "side view" (SV)  or even "side  firing". For example, more-or-less at random, [here is a Panasonic one](http://www.semicon.panasonic.co.jp/ds4/LNJ353W83RA_E.pdf):

[image: http://www.semicon.panasonic.co.jp/ds4/LNJ353W83RA_E.pdf]

I don't  think the recommended footprints necessarily conform to the standard ones, but some probably do.

Here's a photo from the catalog showing the way it goes.

[image]

BTW, there  are also LEDs that emit light toward the mounting surface (usually with a protruding lens that fits into a hole in the PCB).

Comment: In your image, the middle drawing looks like the lens of the LED is pointing upwards. I would have expected the solder footprint to be such that the lens is to the side if that makes any sense. What am I missing?

Comment: There are three views of the LED- top one is looking into the lens from the side, middle one is looking down on the board, bottom one is looking at the opposite side from the lens. No footprint.

Comment: The ones that go down to the other side of PCB are called Rear View, as I found out when I almost accidentally ordered some which I thought were normal facing ones haha

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could take a look at laser diodes? They will emit the light to whatever direction you point them to. All other types IMHO emit the light to all directions. Example: http://www.dx.com/p/6mm-5mw-650nm-red-laser-diode-dc-5v-150906.

Though these are not SMD-like.